# Converting FMS RTMP Live stream to RTSP for BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, rtsp, rtmp, flash-media-server, live-streaming

Is there a way to convert a RTMP live stream from FMS 4.5 to RTSP for a BlackBerry App? I have a FMS 4.5 server deployed would like to enable live streaming to BlackBerry users via a native app and according to BlackBerry documentation, the only protocols that can support Live Streaming on a BlackBerry device are HTTP & RTSP.

[BlackBerry Support for media streaming](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11844/feature_media_streaming_438282_11.jsp)

Comment: What did you try? The first search gives http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010019/rtsp-to-rtmp-streaming This is RTSP to RTMP but most probably you will find you answer nearest.

Answer (score 0):

You could use rtmpdump in a cgi and write to stdout, wouldn't be rtsp, just http.
This is how I used play rtmp streams off NBC without flash.
The script is called with the rtmp stream as an argument. 
such as:

http://example.com/cgi-bin/nbc.cgi?nbcv=url-minus-domain/movie.mp4

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi
import subprocess

rtmpdump='/usr/local/bin/rtmpdump';
# use the quiet switch we are writing the video to stdout.
quiet='-q';

# swf verification
swfUrlswitch='-s';
swfUrl='http://www.nbc.com/assets/video/3-0/swf/NBCVideoApp.swf';

rtmpUrlswitch='-r';
rtmpbase= 'rtmp://cp81777.edgefcs.net/ondemand/';
# grab the argument
a=cgi.FieldStorage()

rtmpUrl=rtmpbase+a.getvalue('nbcv');

pargs=[rtmpdump,quiet,swfUrlswitch,swfUrl,rtmpUrlswitch,rtmpUrl]

# http headers 
if rtmpUrl[-3:]=='mp4':
    print 'Content-Type: video/x-mp4'
if rtmpUrl[-3:]=='flv':
    print 'Content-Type: video/x-flv'

# make sure you print a blank line after the header.
print ''
# call rtmpdump
subprocess.Popen(pargs)
```